# Manipulate columns by their name pattern in a R data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table, `DT`; some of its column names have a pattern. How can I concisely (ie, in one line of code) write do something like

```
DT[pat1>0, pat1:=1]
DT[pat2>0, pat2:=1]
DT[pat3>0, pat3:=1]
```

Toy data:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(id=rnorm(5), pat1=sample(0:3, 5, T), pat2=sample(0:3, 5, T), pat3=sample(0:3, 5, T))
DT
##            id pat1 pat2 pat3
## 1: -0.6264538    0    1    3
## 2:  0.1836433    0    2    0
## 3: -0.8356286    2    3    2
## 4:  1.5952808    1    1    0
## 5:  0.3295078    3    3    1


DT[pat1>0, pat1:=1]
DT[pat2>0, pat2:=1]
DT[pat3>0, pat3:=1]
DT
##            id pat1 pat2 pat3
## 1: -0.6264538    0    1    1
## 2:  0.1836433    0    1    0
## 3: -0.8356286    1    1    1
## 4:  1.5952808    1    1    0
## 5:  0.3295078    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it must be on one line, this loop does it:

```
for (j in paste0('pat',1:3)) DT[get(j) > 0, (j) := 1L]
```

Comment: am accepting this one as it's the easiest to read. @nicola's answer is also great and the explicit `function(x)` makes the code easier to be recycled. I will test which one performs best in terms of execution time (my guess is nicola's). one random thought that crosses my mind: would be great if future versions of `data.table` had more wrapper functions.

Comment: My guess would be that akrun's will be faster than mine as well, especially as you increase the number of columns modified. Like nicola's, akrun's doesn't make repeated calls to `[.data.table` in a loop like mine does. (If so, the only relative merit of my answer is its readability.) I'm not sure what you mean by wrapper functions in this context, but `dplyr` seems to have a ton of special-use functions that work on `data.table`s; I hope to learn/try its syntax soon.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
DT[, paste0("pat", 1:3) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(x > 0)),
   .SDcols = paste0("pat", 1:3)]
            id pat1 pat2 pat3
#1: -0.6264538    0    1    1
#2:  0.1836433    0    1    0
#3: -0.8356286    1    1    1
#4:  1.5952808    1    1    0
#5:  0.3295078    1    1    1
```

Comment: Subsetting, by using the `i` part of `DT[i,j]`, may be beneficial in terms of speed.

Comment: @eddi Ah, I guess I was wrong. I thought that loading only the subset that needs to be edited into `.SD` would save time, but that's not so for the edit here. The `set` approach in akrun's answer is the right way to go here, right?

Comment: @Frank I'm not sure what "right" means here - all 3 options work and have their advantages/disadvantages; this particular one is what I normally do but that doesn't really mean anything

Answer (score 4):

You could also try `set`

```
indx <- grep('pat', names(DT))

for(j in indx){set(DT, i= which(DT[[j]] >0), j=j, value=1) }

 DT
 #           id pat1 pat2 pat3
 #1: -0.6264538    0    1    1
 #2:  0.1836433    0    1    0
 #3: -0.8356286    1    1    1
 #4:  1.5952808    1    1    0
 #5:  0.3295078    1    1    1
```

Also, as @Frank commented, the 'indx' object is not needed as it can be used within the `for` loop.

Comment: And.. as a one liner (per OP's demand): `for(j in grep('pat',names(DT))) set(DT, i= which(DT[[j]] >0), j=j, value=1)`  !

Comment: @Frank Thanks, I thought about that, but it will be a bit too crowded for a single line.